# algebraic topology and 3d/4d printing

Tags: computational-geometry

I googled for papers on applying algebraic topology to 3d/4d printing. It just seems to me that there has to be a connection. Any help, kind audience?

edit: 4d printing means 1-parameter families of 3d printed objects.  Movies with 3d printed objects, one object per frame.

Comment: The title refers to "printing" (what's 4d printing?), but the body of the question does not.  What are you looking for?  I don't think the question can be given a useful answer without more details.

Comment: Why do you insist on algebraic topology? How exactly did you come to this idea?

Comment: @HenryCohn Presumably, 4D printing is 3D printing with programable shape transformation (i.e., the time axis gives the 4th dimension) like this: http://www.ted.com/talks/skylar_tibbits_the_emergence_of_4d_printing?language=en

Comment: Thanks for the link!  My first thought was that it was the analogue of 3d printing for people who live in $\mathbb{R}^4$.

Comment: This [feature article](http://www.ams.org/samplings/feature-column/fc-2014-03) from AMS explores some mathematics used in 3D printing, but the involved mathematics is related to computational geometry, not algebraic topology.

Comment: I edited your question, putting in a comment to let people know what "4d printing" convention you are using.  Feel free to revert my edits.  Your algebraic topology tag wasn't quite appropriate, even though you were asking for connection.  As far as I am aware, people take inspiration from objects in mathematics.  In 3 and 4 dimensions, probably you want things like the Hopf fibration, minimal surfaces, incompressible surfaces, various types of fractals, knots, links, compressing surfaces, and so on...

Comment: Vasili: I suspect your question was closed for fairly trivial reasons. As written, it does not have the form of a proper MO question, in that you are asking an extremely open-ended question with little proper form, little criteria for a response being an answer.  And by insisting on the connections being to algebraic topology (and your original algebraic topology tag) probably got the "wrong crowd" reading your question.  If you edit it a little more, you could likely have it re-opened.

Comment: @Ryan: Do you think this question has *anything* to do with art?

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, of course, that's why I put the math-and-art  tag on the question.

Answer (score 7):

There are certainly many "digital artists" who are inspired
by topology in their 3D-print designs. E.g., Torolf Sauermann:

 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
[image]

 
 
 
 
 
 
 
 
<sup>(Image from [this web site](http://74fdc.wordpress.com/2012/05/21/3d-printer-art-the-future-of-footwear-sole-design/).)</sup>

Comment: This link may also be interesting: http://plus.maths.org/content/3d-printing

Comment: ... and our very own Henry Segerman: http://mathoverflow.net/users/6015/henry-segerman

Answer (score 6):

I think one *excellent* 4d printing project that (to my knowledge) nobody has done yet would be to print the *Optiverse*.  This is John Sullivan's minimal elastic bending energy version of the $\mathbb RP^2$-midpoint Shapiro-Morin sphere eversion.

http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~jms/Papers/isama/eversions.pdf

[image]

This would take quite a bit of work as you would have to make some fairly intelligent choices of how to make cuts in the surface in order to see what's going on, yet not lose track that this is a sphere.

But who knows, maybe Sullivan has a version of this on his office desk?  It wouldn't surprise me.